# How to use foreign id as primary id in spring boot jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way to use primary key of another entity as primary key without using Embeddable or Id class. e.g:

```
@Table(name = "employee")
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
```

Here, Person is another entity and and person_id is the primary key. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are `Person`  & `Employee` @OneToOne related?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if this is the only paramter constructing the PK you can do it like this

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private Long personId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
```

But if this is the case there is no use of doing it, if Employee has the same primary key then they should be in the same table, no need to separate them in 2 tables.

In case we are dealing with composite primary key which contains person then we need to create an embedable key:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey{

   @Column(name="person_id")
   private Long personId;
   ...  // other attributes
}

public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId CompositeKey employeeId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;
```

Another note, where is your relation annotation, you should be have OneToOne annotation on your person reference :

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Person person;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was already familiar with such stuff. Didn't want to use separate table or embeddable for only one field. Maybe, spring with work on this in future. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that `Employee` could extend `Person`? If this is the case then with inheritance it goes in a 'natural' way.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Getter
   private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {

}
```

Comment: So if i delete a row from Employee then it would be deleted from Person table as well? Or what if two columns in both tables have same name but different purpose?

Comment: @user2083529 1st Yes. I have no clue why otherwise should use same Id unless want to point as **same** 'entity'. 2nd you can override the field in inheriting class but I would not do that but instead name the fields better by purpose if possible.

Comment: I will up vote it. though it is not a solution in my case.

Comment: @user2083529 Maybe you could add some use case / why do you want to do such thing in your question? Is it that you have to live some db design you cannot change?

Comment: yes, db design problem. I want to implement KISS (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS-Prinzip) . Using foreign key as primary will save my sever from a lot of computation time and me from writing some codes.